# I like flying and I like airports. Is there a job for me so I can fly for free?

Tags: air-travel

I don't like traveling in its classical sense. I don't like going to tourist attractions, trying new foods, meeting locals, learning history or traditions. Instead, I like moving around. I like entering and leaving airports, planes, hotels, taxis. I also like spontaneous flights to spontaneous destinations.

What are some jobs I can do so someone else can pay for all that?

Comment: A lot of jobs would even pay you to fly! But "spontaneous flights to spontaneous destinations" may be more difficult.

Comment: Pilot? Drug courier?

Comment: As an internal auditor with an international company, I got to travel around my home country and to make quite a few overseas trips. ‘Spontaneous’ trips were pretty rare though

Comment: Pilot, flight attendant, air marshal... Also any job where you may be required to provide installation or maintenance service at remote customer locations (of course this needs to be specialised enough that the company does not have local people close to the customer locations).

Comment: "Spontaneous flight", but without enjoying attraction, new food and history? This is difficult. Crew flights, but never spontaneously (cargo pilots may travel in most different locations). Travel vlogers may travel spontaneously, but they need to add destination things (but if you are very into just the travel part). So it remains: do businesses (import/export)

Comment: What about enlising in the military? You might get to fly “spontaneously” and are not necessarily expected to enjoy tourists attractions. Also, seaman for the merchant navy. You also get to fly to random places (to join a ship).

Comment: @jcaron can confirm for most very specialized OEMs (think oil / gas platforms, large industrial equipment...). Some positions are so specialized that only a handful of people qualify

Comment: Friend of mine flies for free: His mother was a flight attendant and  has a transferable life-time stand-by pass on a major US carrier. That's the unicorn of free flying from  40-50 years ago. His mom is in her 90s.

Comment: Flying for fun is different than flying for a job.